# Problem with nested variables in MuleSoft 4

Tags: mulesoft, mule4, mule-esb

We are having a problem with nested variables in a Mulesoft configruation.  I have simplified this from actual usage so it is easier to understand and test.  There is an environment variable named "env_name" with a value of "dev". Then there is a variable called "dev_string" with the value of "this is the dev string". Finally we have a  variable "finalString" value is "${${env_name}_string}" so we expect it should look up env_name and resolve to "${dev_string}" then lookup dev_string and resolve to the value of dev_string which is "this is the dev string" However at startup we get the following message: "Couldn't find configuration property value for key ${${env_name} from properties provider"  It looks like it is finding the opening "${" and just matching it with the first closing "}" instead of realizing there is another lookup in the middle.

Comment: What is the usage intended for finalString? Is it a Mule variable? Are you using it in configuration of a connector? Please provide details. Also note that MuleSoft is the name of the company. The product you are using is Mule 4, not MuleSoft 4.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not fully sure because there are no details in the question however the problem seems to be mixing [configuration properties](https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-runtime/4.3/configuring-properties) and variables. What you are calling an environment variable could be a configuration property or an [operating system environment variable](https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-runtime/4.3/configuring-properties#environment-variables). In both cases they are set statically at application initialization. Their value can be expanded using `${name}` inside a string also at initialization time. They are not to be confused with Mule variable which are dynamically set during flow execution and are used inside expressions as `#[ vars.name ]`. You can not use `${...}` to expand variables.

I'll assume that finalString is a Mule variable and env_name and dev_string are configuration properties or environment variables. You can not expand nested configuration properties using `${}` but if you are assigning to a Mule variable you should instead use the [p()](https://docs.mulesoft.com/dataweave/2.4/dataweave-runtime-functions#function_p) function in an expression instead. Luckily it allows to evaluate the name dynamically because it is an expression.

Example:

```
<set variable variableName="finalString" value="#[ p(p('dev_name') ++ '_string')]"
```